# How to save daily changes in a virtualbox to a live USB

Tags: usb, virtualbox, backup, sync

I have been successful in installing, booting and using Ubuntu into my 64gb USB flash drive.

What I plan is to do is to convert a copy of my USB key to a virtual image and boot it using virtualbox. (No problem there either!)

*My question is:* **Is there a way for me to save daily changes from my virtual machine to my Ubuntu installed (unlike liveCD) USB pendrive so I can use that to boot and continue where I left off on my Virtualbox?**

*Note: I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a 64gb pendrive with 4 partitions. One 8gb fat32, the 2nd is /home, the 3rd is Linux Swap and the last 5.3gb is just an empty parition.*

Comment: It's more of a VirtualBox question, so I re-edited your question and added a tag for it...

Comment: ah yes... I think I made my question too specific for virtualbox. I think my question would be better if I asked, how to sync from one drive to another.

Comment: Edit your own question and be more specific.  Think about it for 5 minutes: What do you have, what do you want?

Comment: Ok... let's see.. (What I have) I have a USB pendrive with a live Ubuntu. I can boot from it, use it and develop. (What I want) I want to migrate my existing Ubuntu installation from my pendrive to a virtualbox image. But as I use the virtualbox image, my pendrive becomes outdated. Is there a way to sync data from virtualbox image to pendrive. Probably every end of the day.

Comment: :-)  Then your question is not too specific to virtualbox and I cannot help you as I only use it to run virtual machines, not to create them.  (upvoted your question to attract more intelligent people then me!)

Comment: And edited your question to make it more clear.  If you disagree, revert the changes!  ;-)

Comment: @user68185 I've found a nifty way to ensure low-rep users actually do edits when reading comments: as you're typing the word "edit" anyway, enclose it in square brackets and it becomes an [edit] which those less-experienced users (rep 1 etc) will find easier then "Edit? What edit are they talking about???" and then finding a 6-point small little non-obvious edit button in 50% grey...  :-)

Comment: @Fabby, great job at editing my question. Thanks!

Comment: @user68186, I have updated my questions as per your request. I have also found out rsync. I'm still reading its capabilities. I'll try them out this weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want to do, is use your flash drive as the 'harddrive' in Virtualbox. This way all your changes will be reflected on the flash drive.

In order to do this, you will need to make a virtual hard drive that points to the physical device, then use the virtual hard drive with Virtualbox.

Use the following command, replacing /dev/sda with the device that is your flash drive
`sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename /path/to/file.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sda`

See https://superuser.com/questions/495025/use-physical-harddisk-in-virtual-box for more details.

If what you're trying to do, is run two individual systems in Virtualbox and on the Flash Drive, and then 'synchronise' the changes back and forth, you can use rsync to synchronise the files, if both systems are running at the same time. 
But you can't synchronise all the files, as that'd definitely cause problems unless the two systems are identical, so you will have to settle for something like your home directory for instance. Seeing as you have /home on a separate partition, you can also use my above instructions to make a virtual hard drive that points to that single partition, and mount it with Virtualbox.

Comment: It's the second one that you got it. I guess am on the right direction then. I'll do a bit of experimenting with rsync. Just in time as I forgot my usb drive back in my room. I can get my work from git, but setting up the environment and tools is such a pain. eugh.

Answer (score 0):

After running some test and actually using it, here's the command for rsync that I am happy with:

```
rsync -aAXv –exclude={“/dev/*”,”/proc/*”,”/sys/*”,”/tmp/*”,”/run/*”,”/mnt/*”,”/media/*”,”/lost+found”, “/boot/*”} /media/sda1/* /media/sdb1/ –delete -u --dry-run
```

If I am satisfied, I remove --dry-run to make the changes.